# Subtracting columns in snowflake/DBT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have two columns one with pick objects and another with unpicked objects for each client.

I need to create a column with the final objects for example:

| Customer_ID | Picked. | Unpicked. | . Final Cart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 799235 | shirt, pants, glasses | . glasses. | shirt, pants |
| 799246 | dress, pants, glasses | . pants, dresses | glasses |

I was trying to do this in Snowflake but it looks like none of the defined functions work.

And a customer can add and remove an item as many times as they want, I'm only interested in the final values.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley, dbt jinja isn't useful for this problem, because it's (almost always) compiled before SQL run-time, so it doesn't have access to the values.

This *can*, however be solved with Snowflake SQL.  The basic pattern is to flatten out the values, then do your subtraction, then to aggregate them back together.

Here's some code:

```sql
with carts as (
    select 799235 as customer_id, array_construct('shirt', 'pants', 'glasses')  as picked, array_construct('glasses') as unpicked
    union
    select 799246, array_construct('dress', 'pants', 'glasses'), array_construct('pants', 'dress')
),

picked_expanded as (
    select
        carts.customer_id,
        picked.value::varchar as item
    from carts, lateral flatten ( input => carts.picked ) as picked
),

unpicked_expanded as (
    select
        carts.customer_id,
        unpicked.value::varchar as item
    from carts, lateral flatten ( input => carts.unpicked ) as unpicked
),

combined as (
    select * from picked_expanded
    except
    select * from unpicked_expanded
),

agg as (
    select
        customer_id,
        array_agg(item) as final_cart
    from combined
    group by 1
)

select * from agg
```

Which gives the result:

| CUSTOMER_ID | FINAL_CART |
| --- | --- |
| 799246 | ["glasses"] |
| 799235 | ["shirt", "pants"] |